# GetEnumSelect list is not working for me. How to resolve this?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem and I am not sure how to fix this.

When I use the GetEnum Selectlist I have an error.

"The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

When I look at my data model and the view it looks correct and I am not sure why it will not work. Can anyone help me? I am using mvc core

```
namespace(etc) 

 public enum Gender 
{
    Male, Female, NonBinary, TransGender, Intersex, IPreferNotToSay
}

public enum Title
{
  Mr, Mrs, Miss, Ms, Mx  
}


public class Patient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Title Title { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Gender Gender { get; set; } 
}
}
```

View page: Create.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Title" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Title>()" class="form-control">
                    <option>Select Title</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>



  </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The title is coming up with a red line inside the GetenumSelectList

Comment: Hi @user450157, what is your version of asp.net core? Did you use `@model Patient` in your view?

Comment: I was going to post about this problem too. When try to use @model Patient it says I am missing an assembly reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer.

For some reason when using the sp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<>(),

I had to do it this way to solve this issue:

Html.GetEnumSelectList<SolutionName.Data.Models.Title>()

It has fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but maybe the problem is caused because the Gender and Title property of class Patient is called same as the enum.

Comment: unfortunately I did try converting one to a string and removing the enum but still was a problem unfortuately

Comment: @user450157 What do you mean? I mean that the property has exact same name as the type. It must be called different.